# Failure to model a building from image

Tags: texturing, uv

When I look at this model from right side, it looks good:

[image]

But when I look from the left side, something seems off..

[image]

I started few days ago to learn how to use blender and now I am stuck, if you can help, that would be much appreciated.

[image]

All the faces are there, I think this is a bug, sometimes works perfectly from left side and sometimes from right, and even sometimes does not work in both sides.

[image]

This is how it looks with backface culling, tried to recalculate the normals but the problem stays there.

EDIT: I activated "Backface culling" while in "Viewport Shading" and this fixed the entire problem.

[image]

Comment: In the lower picture it looks like you extruded the edges and not the face?
In that case, just select the extruded parts and delete them, then select and extrude the face afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but everything is there, all the faces, I think this may be a bug with my blender, I updated my question above with more details.

Comment: It indeed looks ok from above, that would make me check for one thing that can always mess up the object. Normals, if you check the "Face Orientation", it may be that there is one or more face with flipped normals. You can check it by activating the "Face Orientation" in the Viewport Overlays  menu in the top right of the 3D View. Blue faces face outwards, red inwards, should always be blue when looking at it from the front.

Comment: I just did what you said ( added a new image ), I tried to recalculate the normals but no success. So when I look from left side, I only see right side, but when I look from right side, I only see left side.

Comment: When recalculating the normals, they all became blue but the problem was still there.

Comment: At this point i would say the easiest way to figure out what's wrong would be if you add the file with [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).
You can take out all but the affected part, but please consider not to change too much as that can make it harder to find the problem.